# Vampy and Sonic Annotator on OS X Yosemite

Tags: c++, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

Just [getting started with Vampy](http://isophonics.org/content/getting-started-vampy) on OS X.

Installed VAMP, Sonic Annotator and Sonic Visualizer via the OS X Binaries.

I have placed the `vampy.dylib` file, along with some of the Vamp example plugins into the Vamp Plugin path (`~/Library/Audio/Plugins/Vamp`):

```
~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Vamp/
├── PyMFCC.py
├── PySpectralCentroid.py
├── PySpectralFeatures.py
├── PyZeroCrossing.py
├── VamPyTemplate.py
├── vamp-example-plugins.cat
├── vamp-example-plugins.dylib
├── vamp-example-plugins.n3
├── vamp-simple-host
└── vampy.dylib
```

Confirm the Vampy Plugins are working via the Sonic Visualizer GUI:

[image: Screen Shot of Sonic Visualizer with Vamp Plugins]

The list function on the sonic-annotator CLI returns all of the Vamp plugins, but not Vampy itself not any of the python plugin files:

`$ sonic-annotator -l
    Creating extension manager.
    Cleaning locals...
    Cleaning module...
    vamp:vamp-example-plugins:amplitudefollower:amplitude
    vamp:vamp-example-plugins:fixedtempo:acf
    # No Vampy as expected`

On the both vampy and non-vampy plugins the main vamp-simple-host feature works:

```
$ vamp-simple-host vampy:vampy-sf3
expected data...

$ vamp-simple-host vamp-example-plugins:zerocrossing:zerocrossings some.wav
expected data...
```

Using the list functions in vamp-simple-host is very verbose about all the Vampy plugins, but also quite redundant. Almost not data about the plugins with `.dylib` extension.

I have also installed the Vamp SDK in home directory and installed `libsndfile` via homebrew:

`brew install libsndfile`

Any ideas of what to check next?

Comment: So you have two commands, one of which works and one doesn't. What do you get from `which vamp-simple-host` and `which sonic-annotator` ? Are they in the same location?

Comment: Good question. No. After running `which sonic-annotator` and `which vamp-simple-host` I remember that I had put `vamp-simple-host` in the Vamp Plugins directory and `sonic-annotator` in `/usr/local/lib`. Moved `sonic-annotator`, ran `hash -r` to reset Bash's command hash. Still not seeming to get `sonic-annotator` to see Vampy though. Same output.

Comment: Sounds like it depends on exactly how vamp plugins are detected and loaded. Any vamp experts in the house? What do we call you - vampires? :)

Comment: ^^ which probably means a pathing problem of some sort.